# Python duplicate words written into an outFile - where to define "i"

Tags: python, loops, file, count, duplicates

*I sincerely apologize if this is the incorrect way to ask my question. This is my first time posting in Stack.*

My inFile is six edited lines of the poem do not go gentle into the night. It should print out an outFile that contains the lines that contain a word that is greater than 3 letters, that is a duplicate. In example "rage rage against the dying of the light" would be printed because of "rage".

edit: When I run this it gives me an error saying "i" is undefined.

Oh, and I can't use any modules.

Here is my code:

```
def duplicateWordLines(inFile,outFile):
    inFile=open(inFileName, "r")
    outFile=open(outFileName, "w")

    for line in inFile:
        words=line.split() #split the lines
        og=[] #orignal words
        dups=[] #duplicate words

        for word in words: #for each word in words
            if og.count(i)>0 and line not in dups: #if the word appears more than once and not already in duplicates
                dups.append(line) #add to duplicates
            else: #if not a duplicate 
                og.append(i) #add to the original list - not to worry about it

    for line in dups: #for the newly appended lines
        outFile.write(line+'\n') #write in the outFile 


#test case
inFileName="goodnightPoem.txt"
outFileName="goodnightPoemDUP.txt"

duplicateWordLines(inFileName,outFileName)

#should print 
#rage rage against the dying of the light
#do not go gentle into that good good night
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just by glancing at your code, I can see that it doesn't compile. `og.count(i)` --`i` is not defined anywhere

Comment: Probably you should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and come back to this question. The most critical points to me are that you do not report what problem you experience, comment on why were you expecting something different and do not provide enough context to run your code *as is*.

Comment: @HugoRad--is a duplicate a word that appears more than twice in anywhere in a line or a word that repeats such as "Rage, rage..."?

Comment: @DarryIG it is a word that duplicates in one line. So if "rage rage..." was in more than one line both of the lines would show up. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out...

```
def duplicateWordLines(inFile,outFile):
    inFile=open(inFileName, "r")
    outFile=open(outFileName, "w")

    for line in inFile:

        # split the lines
        words=line.split() 

        # remove all words less than 3 characters
        words = [word for word in words if len(word)>3]

        # make the list a set, so all duplicates are removed
        no_dups = set(words)

        # if there are more words in the words list than the
        # no duplicate list, we must have a duplicate, so 
        # print the line
        if len(words) > len(no_dups):
            outFile.write(line+'\n') #write in the outFile 

#test case
inFileName="file.txt"
outFileName="file_1.txt"

duplicateWordLines(inFileName,outFileName)
```

Regarding the i is undefined error, let's look at your for loop

```
for word in words: #for each word in words
            if og.count(i)>0 and line not in dups: #if the word appears more than once and not already in duplicates
                dups.append(line) #add to duplicates
            else: #if not a duplicate 
                og.append(i) #add to the original list - not to worry about it
```

You don't actually define `i` anywhere, your loop defines `word`.  You are blending a smart loop, i.e. `for word for words` with a range loop, like `for i in range(0,len(words))`.  If we were to fix your loop, I think it would look something like this...

```
for word in words: #for each word in words
            if og.count(word)>0 and line not in dups: #if the word appears more than once and not already in duplicates
                dups.append(line) #add to duplicates
            else: #if not a duplicate 
                og.append(word) #add to the original list - not to worry
```

Comment: I misread the goal the first time, and the code only printed the duplicate word.  Now it is fixed to print the entire line if the duplicate greater than 3 characters appears.